How do we solve the proposed limit $\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)^2}{\sqrt[3]{x^6+1}}$?
I'm trying to solve the following limit: $$\lim _{x\to \infty}\frac{\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)^2}{\sqrt[3]{x^6+1}}$$
What I did first was to expand the numerator and after that I divided both numerator and denominator by the highest power in the denominator what is $x^2$.
After doing so, i ended up having $5$ as a result but the answer should be $4$, so I am stuck at the moment.
Could someone tell me what I did wrong?

HINT
I would start with noticing that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\left(\sqrt{x^{2} + 1} + x\right)^{2}}{\sqrt[3]{x^{6} + 1}} = \frac{\left(\sqrt{1 + 1/x^{2}} + 1\right)^{2}}{\sqrt[3]{1 + 1/x^{6}}}
\end{align*}
Can you proceed from here?

Thank you both made it clear, but i still would like to know where i got it wrong. After expanding de denominator we have 2x^2 + 2xsqrt(x^2+1)+1, after diving this numerator by x^2 im having 5 instead of 2. Can you spot where is my mistake?

Can't you see after expansion of numerator (not denominator) as you did in the comment and division by $x^2$  and taking limit you get $2+2+0$?

ooh, now i see. Thank you

Some details can be given after Atila Correia's hint.
$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)^2}{\sqrt[3]{x^6+1}}$$
Factor $x^2$ and $x^6$,
$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{\left(\sqrt{x^2(1+\tfrac1{x^2})}+x\right)^2}{\sqrt[3]{x^6(1+\tfrac1{x^6})}}$$
Then,
$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{\left(x\sqrt{1+\tfrac1{x^2}}+x\right)^2}{x^2\sqrt[3]{1+\tfrac1{x^6}}}$$
and
$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{\left(\sqrt{1+\tfrac1{x^2}}+1\right)^2}{\sqrt[3]{1+\tfrac1{x^6}}}$$
Since numerator and denominator have limits
$$\frac{\left(\sqrt{1+\lim_ {x\to \infty}\tfrac1{x^2}}+1\right)^2}{\sqrt[3]{1+\lim_{x\to \infty}\tfrac1{x^6}}}.$$
The answer is $\frac{(\sqrt{1+0}+1)^2}{\sqrt[3]{1+0}}=4.$

Your idea is fine and after this step
$$\frac{\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)^2}{\sqrt[3]{x^6+1}}=\frac{2x^2+2x\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}{\sqrt[3]{x^6+1}}$$
(which is not strictly necessary but it is not wrong) then dividing both numerator and denominator by $x^2$, we obtain
$$\frac{2+2\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}+\frac1{x^2}}{\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1{x^6}}}$$
which tends to $4$ and not to $5$, this is what you did wrong.

As an alternative to the answer that has already been given, notice that the Laurent series of the function is
$$4 + \frac2{x^2} + \mathcal O\left(\left(\frac1x\right)^4\right)$$
Which clearly goes to $4$ as $x\to\infty$. I understand that this requires more advanced notions that you probably don't have yet, but since an exhaustive answer about the basic method has been provided already, this is an interesting extra fact.
